# Getting method level CPU time spent through MBeans

Tags: java, jmx

```
  ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime()
```

provides time spent only at Thread level. I'm looking for a way to get CPU time spent at method level within a Thread.

Does Oracle/OpenJDK Java support anything like that?

I'm invoking ThreadMXBean APIs on remote JVM through MBeanServerConnection and I can't invoke from within the code running on remote JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The thread cpu time is cumulative so you can sample it before a method, then again afterwards and the delta of the two samples is the cpu time consumed in the method.

Comment: Actually, I can't modify the Java code on the target JVM. I forgot to mention that it's a JMX connection to a remote JVM.

Comment: Ah, that is a horse of a different color.... Take a look at JVisualVM or Java Mission Control (JMC). Both can instrument your code remotely and I think they can capture cpu utilization.

Comment: I need programmatic / api access to this information.